# Basic CRUD returning 404 (MySQL + Express + VueJS + NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, vue.js

I have done the following sample: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Kju3DovLrg and something is broken my connections.

I can only see this error in my browser:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/pedidos 404 (Not Found)
```

My only one modification was to change the table to add one more column.

My server.js

```
var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")

var pedidos = require("./routes/pedidos")
var cors = require("cors")

var port = 3000

var app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use("/api", pedidos)

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port >>> ' + port)
})
```

My dev webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  dev: {

    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',

    // Various Dev Server settings
    host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
    port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
    proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
      }
    },
    autoOpenBrowser: false,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
    poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-

  }
```

My pedidos.js

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
const Pedido = require("../model/Pedido")

//Get All pedidos
router.get("/pedidos", (req, res) => {
    Pedido.findAll()
        .then(pedidos => {
            res.json(pedidos)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send("error: " + err)
        })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Paste `pedidos`  routes as well.

Comment: port = 3000  but *//localhost:8080/api/pedidos* has 8080 ?

Comment: `app.use("/api", pedidos)` , show us the code for the route specifically. Also check if your route accepts the new mysql schema properly.

Comment: I've added pedidos.js from routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart the frontend server，vue.config.js change need restart by runing 'yarn serve'

Comment: How is your vue-project created? I watch the video that you post. It look like  created with vue-cli 2.x! You need use the same version

Comment: It looks like I needed a vue files config reboot after some test times with difference proxyTable settings ¬¬'

Comment: Yes! It cannot auto reboot.